# How to download file using django-storage sftp?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, sftp

I'm using django storage module to store file in a location using sftp and now we need to download same file from sftp.

Any suggestions?

models.py

```
from storages.backends.sftpstorage import SFTPStorage

SFS = SFTPStorage()

class Configurations(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='configurations', storage=SFS)
    descriptions = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.sftpstorage.SFTPStorage'

SFTP_STORAGE_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SFTP_STORAGE_ROOT = '/var/www/media/'
SFTP_STORAGE_PARAMS = {
    'username': 'root',
    'password': 'password',
    'allow_agent': False,
    'look_for_keys': False,
}
# SFTP_KNOWN_HOST_FILE = '~/.ssh/known_hosts'
SFTP_STORAGE_INTERACTIVE = False
```

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

from .models import (CustomConfigurations)
from .serializers import (CustomConfigurationsSerializers)


class ToolCustomConfigurationsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomConfigurations.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser,)
    serializer_class = CustomConfigurationsSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset.all().order_by('-id')
        return queryset
```

serializer.py

```
class CustomConfigurationsSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomConfigurations
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
def download(self, request, pk=None):

    try:
        obj = CustomConfigurations.objects.get(id=pk)
    except CustomConfigurations.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    if SFS.exists(obj.file.name):
        file = SFS._read(obj.file.name)
        type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(obj.file.name)
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = u'attachment; filename="{filename}'.format(
            filename=obj.file.name)
        return response
    raise Http404
```