# DRF how to open media url using django storage(sftp)?

Tags: django-rest-framework, sftp, django-storage

I'm using storage SFTP module for saving media now i'm facing issues to open image url path as we know there is no media is project directory because i am using sftp.

Please suggest me the best way to render back end images using django rest.

Detailed info:  [models, view and setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618855/how-to-download-file-using-django-storage-sftp)

Comment: Hi, i am also trying to do the same. If you got or have the answer for the same can you please upload it here so that i can also try it. Thanks